# Spring WebFlux endpoints in 8080 port can be accessible via metrics:9443 port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

In my Spring boot application, I have a dependency on WebFlux as `spring-boot-starter-webflux`, and at server startup, it says that the application is ready with Netty.
NettyWebServer: `Netty started on port(s): 8080`

Also, I have Spring Boot Actuator dependency, and expose metrics endpoint on port 9443 `spring-boot-starter-actuator`

but when I start the application I can access my rest endpoints via mertics port which is a bug I think:
`http://localhost:9443/api/`

can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Spring Boot + Spring Framework. There is no known workaround for now. [You can follow the dedicated issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14012).